# How can I populate a message box when mouse cursor enters in a text box?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using 3 text boxes. When I click on 2nd text box I want to show 1st text box value in message box (if 1st text box passed the validations).
Same procedure when i click on 3rd textbox I want to show 1st text box value and 2nd text box value in message box(if 1st text box,2nd text box passed the validations).

Regards,
NSJ

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`onmouseover`](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jmouse.htm) event on the text boxes if you want the function to fire when mousing over.

Use the [`onfocus`](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-Events-OnError-OnFocus-and-More/) event on the text boxes if you want the function to fire when the cursor moves into the control.

Textbox 2 (mouse over):

```
onmouseover="alert(textbox1.value);"
```

Textbox 3 (focus):

```
onfocus="alert(textbox1.value + ' ' + textbox2.value);"
```

If you are using a javascript library like jQuery, it is best to [attach to the events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) through it to maintain separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text="First"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSecond" runat="server" Text="Second"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtThird" runat="server" Text="Third"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#txtSecond").focus(function(){
    alert($("#txtFirst").val());
});
$("#txtThird").focus(function(){
    alert($("#txtFirst").val());
    alert($("#txtSecond").val());
});
});
```